# Connection Error for MSSQL and CheckMK

Tags: ssl, sql-server

I'm running MSSQL 2017 on Server 2016 and monitoring it via CheckMK.  I'm getting critical alerts that state:

*Failed to connect to database (ERROR: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()).]SSL Security error. (SQLState: 08001/NativeError: 18))CRIT, Version: 14.0.1000.169 - Standard Edition*

We have TLS 1.2 enabled and TLS 1.0 and 1.1 disabled.

Does anyone have any idea what this issue may be, and the fix for it?  I thought maybe the Native Client was too old, but after further review I don't believe so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the connection string being built from the plugin.  The plugin builds the connection string from a deprecated provider that only supports TLS 1.0.  Changing the line in the plugin (VBS) line #225

FROM:   'CONN.Provider = "sqloledb"
TO:         CONN.Provider = "SQLNCLI11"

resolves the issue.

(best if you just comment out the line and add the  new provider below it)